# Orthogonality of solution of matrix differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let A(t) be the skew-symmetric matrix of order $N+1$ defined as $A(t)_{i,i+1} := a_i(t)$, $i$ from 1 to $N$, with $a_i(t)$ defined as $\frac{\exp((x_{i}(t) - x_{i-1}(t))/2)}{2}$; the so-called Flaschka variables.

Now I am to show that if the matrix $V$ is a solution to the matrix differential equation $V'(t) = AV(t)$ that satisfies $V(0) = I$, the skew-symmetry of $A$ implies that $V$ is orthogonal. I feel like it should be straightforward, but I can't see a solution. I've tried extracting information about $V^T$ by playing around with the algebra but I'm running in circles.

Answer (score 1):

A hint: note that a matrix $V$ is orthogonal if and only if $V V^T = V^T V = I$. Thus, $V(t)$ is a solution that is orthogonal iff it satisfies this condition for all time $t$, and in particular
$$
\frac{d}{dt}V(t)V(t)^T = \frac{d}{dt}I = 0.
$$
Now work out the left-hand side.

**EDIT: more details**

Assume that $V(t)$ is a solution of the matrix ODE
$$
V'(t) = A(t) V(t).
$$
Further, note that $V(t)$ is orthogonal if and only if $V(t)V(t)^T = V(t)^TV(t) = I$ holds.

Let's express this as the condition that $C(t) := V(t)V(t)^T$ is the identity and differentiate that to obtain
$$
\frac{d}{dt}C(t) = \frac{d}{dt}V(t)V(t)^T = A(t)V(t)V(t)^T + V(t)V(t)^TA(t)^T = A(t)C(t) + C(t)A(t).
$$
Now assume that $A(t)$ is skew symmetric and $V(0)$ is orthogonal, hence $C(0) = I$. Now, $C(t) = I$ is a solution of the above equation (and it is unique by standard ODE theory), hence $V(t)$ is orthogonal for all $t$.

As a side note: indeed there is a small subtlety where we use uniqueness of solutions of ODEs of a derived function $C(t)$. This can more abstractly be viewed as showing that the submanifold of all orthogonal matrices (inside the space of all matrices) is invariant because the ODE vector field is tangent to it.

Comment: I still don't quite see it; we have $\frac{d}{dt} V(t)V(t)^T = V'(t)V(t)^T + V'(t)^TV(t) = AV(t)V^T(t) -V^TAV(t) = 0$. But then what?

Comment: You made an error by swapping the order of $V'(t)^T$ and $V(t)$ in the second term, and realize that $V'(t)^T = (A V(t))^T$. In the end, you should be able to eliminate all the $V(t)$ factors.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the obvious error;for some reason I can't edit my comment anymore. Now, if I'm correct we have that $\frac{d}{dt}V(t)V^T(t) = AV(t)V^T(t) - V(t)V^T(t)A = 0$ (transposing and differentiating commute, right?). I'm thankful for your help so far, but I still can't see what should happen next.

Comment: Yes, so now note that $VV^T = I$ and thus the condition holds, because you used $A^T = -A$. It's better to not use this and then see that $\frac{d}{dt}VV^T = 0$ holds iff $A$ is skew symmetric.

Comment: But I don't see that $VV^T = I$. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: That's the condition that $V(t)$ is orthogonal. This shows that $V(t)$ stays orthogonal iff $A$ is skew symmetric.

Comment: I honestly cannot follow. Why precisely is $VV^T = I$? I *know* that's the condition for V to be orthogonal; that's the very definition. But how does his follow exactly from my last relation?